# Does AWS CLI use SSL when uploading data into S3?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Does the normal AWS CLI use SSL by default when transferring data into S3 with the following command?

```
aws s3 cp source to destination
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default, the AWS CLI uses SSL when communicating with AWS services.

[AWS CLI command reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/)

Comment: _"By default, the AWS CLI uses SSL when communicating with AWS services. For each SSL connection, the AWS CLI will verify SSL certificates."_ from your link

Comment: Latest link: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I just tried running:

```
> aws s3 ls
```

and wireshark reports the response protocol used is TLSv1.2. So, yes it seems to be using SSL even for simple commands like ls.